# Functions of exponential type and associated functions in the sense of Borel.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I am reading some papers by A.F. Leont'ev on expansions of functions as Dirichlet series and the following sentence (or variation thereof) typically appears in the introduction:

Let $L(\lambda)$ be an entire function of exponential type, $\gamma(t)$ *the function associated with it in the sense of Borel*.

My question: What is the definition of $\gamma(t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, but it might help to see one of the papers you're reading (if they're available online anywhere) that this means the Borel transform of an entire function of exponential type.  If your entire function is 
$$L(\lambda) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a^k \lambda_k }{k!} $$
then the Borel transform is
$$ \gamma(t) = \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{a_k}{t^{k+1}} $$
(though I would write $L(z)$ and $\gamma(z)$ personally).